# Use "self" in void () function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, void, self

I have this API that I **cannot** modify in MyViewController.m file:

```
void my_Callback (void* context, xxxxxx::eventType::type eventtype, int code, const myconst)
{

  //do stuff

}
```

I need to call this function:

```
-(void) update
{
  self.textbox.test =@"new text";
}
```

but when I try to do

```
void my_Callback (void* context, xxxxxx::eventType::type eventtype, int code, const myconst)
  {        
      //do stuff
      [self update];        
  }
```

I get error because it can't reconize "self".

I tryed to do:

```
ViewController *newview = [[Viewcontroller alloc]init];
        void my_Callback (void* context, xxxxxx::eventType::type eventtype, int code, const myconst)
        {

          //do stuff
          [newview update];

        }
```

and it finally goes into myfunction "update" but the new text is not set.

How can i get my text updated? Thanks

Comment: You have pass self as a parameter.
Check also this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280017/how-to-call-an-objective-c-method-from-a-c-method

Comment: The text didnt get updated when you tried by creating a new viewcontroller because, the textView you are updating is the self.textbox.text and you are calling the update function for the new viewcontroller. And about the cant recognize "self" error you got, may be because its a static method.

Comment: "my_Callback" is a regular C method, and has no logical association with the other functions in the .m file containing it.  If you want a pointer to any Objective-C object (including "self") you must pass the pointer as a parameter or somehow access it as a global value.

Answer (score 1):

Who calls this callback ? Usually there's a way to put some "user data". In your case it seems to be the `void *context` argument to the callback.

So where you define the callback, you may have a chance to specify the context. There, you can pass it the actual "self", so that you can get it later.

Careful however, as doing so often results in using released instances sooner or later.

Comment: Callback define: typedef void my_Callback (void* context, xxxxxx::eventType::type eventtype, int code, const myconst).

Again, I cannot modify this.

This is how Callback is called:

MyManager->registerEvent ("My listener", &My_Callback, MyManager);

Comment: What is the signature of `MyManager->registerEvent` method? Probably its last argument is the context, in which case you can easily get the `self` from the first argument of your callback, the `context`.

Comment: virtual Result registerEvent(const Stringname, My_Callback listener, void* context) =0 ;

How should I modify this? thanks

Comment: You're probably fine then. Try to figure out what you receive as `context` in your `my_Callback` function. It's probably the `MyManager` object.

Answer (score -2):

Please check if textbox label is initialized.
There might be a possibility that textbox label is un initialized.

Comment: Since his callback is a simple C function, not a part of a method (meaning: there's no such thing as `self` in that scope), `textbox` doesn't yet matter.